# Not able to uninstall the google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I try to uninstall the google chrome using code

```
sudo apt-get purge Google-Chrome-stable
```

I'll get this things

```
sudo: unable to resolve host dell: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Google-Chrome-stable
```

How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`.

You use capital letters for an unknown reason.

Comment: Yeah..  Even for  'sudo apt-get google-chrome-stable'.    It's not working